# Why doesn't Magento reindex search results itself?

Tags: ce-1.4.0.1, reindex

Is there a way to make Magento reindex itself so that frontend product search would work without manually reindexing all indexes?

Comment: Working with Magento i'm learn about this "problem" re-index search result's, generate allot costs to server and need in Community Edition a Module specific for that if your store or your clients need something like that eBay (Magento) recommend to use a Enterprise Edition have a incorporated system and more structure to support auto re-index. by @Rick-Benetti

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can setup a `cron job` to do re-index automatically. Hope the following links will be helpful.

http://www.magentocommerce.com/knowledge-base/entry/ee113-indexing

http://www.magentocommerce.com/wiki/1_-_installation_and_configuration/how_to_setup_a_cron_job

https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15355005/how-to-set-cron-job-for-reindex

Answer (score 0):

In **System > Index Management** if Catalog Search Index is set to **Update on Save** you would expect it to perform a localised search reindex whenever product details are updated.

However, in my experience this doesn't work. I'm guessing you have experienced the same.

You're best bet is setting up a nightly reindex as Su123 suggests. You can get away with only doing it on the catalog search index.

If your client is too impatient to wait til the next day for their changes to appear in the search results, then you might want to advise them to manually reindex the Catalog Search Index via the admin after they've made changes.